# Sorting a list in PHP

Tags: php, html

Alright, so I've just (almost) finished my first little php script. Basically all it does is handling forms. It writes whatever the user put in to the fields of the form to a text file, then I include that text file in the index of the little page I have set up.

So, currently it writes to the beginning of the text file (but doesn't overwrite previous data). But, several users wants this list to be alphabetically sorted instead. So what I want to do is make whatever they submit fall into the list in alphabetical order.

The thing here is also that all I use in the text file are divs. The list is basically 'divided' into 3 parts. 'Title', 'Link', and 'Poster'. All I have done is positioned them with css.

So, can I sort this list (the titles, in this case) alphabetically and still have the 'link' and 'poster' information assigned the way they already are, but just with the titles sorted?

It don't use databases at all on my site, so there is no database handling at all used in this script (mainly because I'm not experienced at all in this).

Comment: users are using this? invest in a database.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though you would need some kind of delimiter in the file to separate the different entries. I would also recommend getting some basic experience with databases. :) If everything is inserted into a set of rows in a table, then you could sort it in all kinds of ways without having to write a whole lot of code.

Comment: So I should really invest in a database, huh? What's the difference between using just a text document and a database (other than making what I want possible with it)? I'm asking because of Kevin's remark.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Extensibility, flexibility and security. If you want to do more things with your script in the future, it will be easier with a database. Also, you are less likely to screw up a database table. However, one little mistake in the writing logic of your script will probably cause you a lot of trouble.

Comment: One word "indexes". A database will be able to index your data and allow for fast lookups (faster than whole file reads) and sorting the data as it is sent to you (versus storing it that way). What happens if your customers want it chronologically? What happens if 2 separate customers want it reverse alpha and chronologically?

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone. I think I'll go with studying some database stuff, and make one...

Although, before I jump the gun, could you possibly recommend me a tutorial or two that I should read when it comes to this?

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest storing the data in the file as either `XML` or `JSON`. PHP can sort the records easily and the sorting will be preserved in the file when the data is read back in.

For example

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/datafile",json_encode($recordset));
```

and when reading the file back in

```
$recordset = json_decode(file_get_contents("/tmp/datafile"));
```

*edit*

but seriously if you have customers and are charging them for your experience and time, use a database, there are many out there (a few mentioned already)

- MySQL
- sqlite
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle
- MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use a database, even a one-file database (such as sqlite), you can group the three fields using a separator such as _ and sort this single-field list

Comment: But, really, using a DB is gonna make your life MUCH MUCH MUCH more easy

Answer (score 0):

If this is a small project for some friends or something and the file shouldn't ever have more than maybe a few hundred lines, the functions you're looking for are "file" and "usort".

If you make sure each row is on its' own line, you can load the lines into an array with "file". You can sort the array using a function to compare items with the "usort" function.